# Slurm not preserving QoS limits

Tags: slurm

I am trying to set QoS limits on the cluster,
to be specific, I want to make sure nobody is able to submit jobs to a specific partition.
So I enable CPU limits on the partition and it works as expected but I see that those limits aren't preserved after restarting slurm, is this normal?

```
$/opt/slurm/bin/scontrol update PartitionName=login-queue QoS=login-node
$scontrol show partition login-queue
PartitionName=login-queue
   AllowGroups=ALL AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL
   AllocNodes=ALL Default=NO QoS=login-node
   DefaultTime=NONE DisableRootJobs=NO ExclusiveUser=NO GraceTime=0 Hidden=NO
   MaxNodes=1 MaxTime=UNLIMITED MinNodes=0 LLN=NO MaxCPUsPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxCPUsPerSocket=UNLIMITED
   NodeSets=login-queue_nodes
   Nodes=login-queue-st-t3medium-1
   PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 RootOnly=NO ReqResv=NO OverSubscribe=NO
   OverTimeLimit=NONE PreemptMode=OFF
   State=UP TotalCPUs=2 TotalNodes=1 SelectTypeParameters=NONE
   JobDefaults=(null)
   DefMemPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxMemPerNode=UNLIMITED
   TRES=cpu=2,mem=3891M,node=1,billing=2
   ResumeTimeout=GLOBAL SuspendTimeout=GLOBAL SuspendTime=GLOBAL PowerDownOnIdle=NO

$systemctl restart slurmctld.service
$scontrol show partition login-queue
PartitionName=login-queue
   AllowGroups=ALL AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL
   AllocNodes=ALL Default=NO QoS=N/A
   DefaultTime=NONE DisableRootJobs=NO ExclusiveUser=NO GraceTime=0 Hidden=NO
   MaxNodes=1 MaxTime=UNLIMITED MinNodes=0 LLN=NO MaxCPUsPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxCPUsPerSocket=UNLIMITED
   NodeSets=login-queue_nodes
   Nodes=login-queue-st-t3medium-1
   PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 RootOnly=NO ReqResv=NO OverSubscribe=NO
   OverTimeLimit=NONE PreemptMode=OFF
   State=UP TotalCPUs=2 TotalNodes=1 SelectTypeParameters=NONE
   JobDefaults=(null)
   DefMemPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxMemPerNode=UNLIMITED
   TRES=cpu=2,mem=3891M,node=1,billing=2
```

`QoS=N/A` after restart

Is there a way to set them so that they are persistant?
Happy to share any other logs that are required